# Microsoft Graph Api - Notification for Undelivered emails - ImmutableId not matching

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm facing an issue correlating failed emails. I'm using Microsoft Graph Api. Below are the steps I have followed.

1. Created a **draft** mail with *Prefer IdType="ImmutableId"* in the header.
2. Sent the draft mail
3. For success scenarios, I have subscribed to Notifications ( webhook ) on the "Sent Items" folder. This is working fine. Here the ImmutableId in the notification is same as the `Id` in the response when I created a draft email.
4. For **failure** scenarios, I have created another Notification subscription with the resource value as below,
   /users/abc.com/mailFolders/{mailFolderID}/messages?$filter=startsWith(subject,'Undeliverable'). Here i'm using a `filter`.

**Problem = The `Id` which arrives in this failure notification is not the same ImmutableId.** So i'm not able to correlate the sent mail to its failed notification. Somehow it looks like the `ImmutableId` is the not the same when subscribed using a filter/query.

Answer (score 0):

ImmutableId refers to the underlying Exchange Store Object, in your send scenario the store object remains the same between drafts and sentItems (all that happens during send is the message is moved) but once a message is sent and even if that same message was received by the sending mailbox (when that message is received) Exchange will create a new Store Object for the received message with an new Id and these objects (the one in SendItems and the one in the inbox) won't be directly linked. The way to correlate them is usually you would use the internetMessageId which would be the same on all copies of the Message. For an undelivered message you would need to get that property by expanding the attached undelivered message eg

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AA..=/attachments/AA.=/?$expand=microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item

Comment: I'm actually trying to find undelivered emails via `webhook Notifications` The way you suggested is more like Polling. Is there a way the internetMessageId can be found and correlated via subscribed Notification? I'm trying to subscribe like this  `/users/abc.com/mailFolders/{mailFolderID}/messages?$filter=startsWith(subject,'Undeliverable')`.

Comment: No the way web hooks are implemented in the Graph doesn't allow you to send extra message properties as part of the webhook notification but for undeliverable messages that wouldn't help anyway as the information you need will be in the attachment.